# How to change the format of a column inside shiny server

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I loading a `.csv` inside shiny and want to change the format of the column `date` to a specific date format. My code so far:

```
 shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    ...
 #read csv
    df <- reactive({ read.csv(foo, sep = ";")                      
          }) 
 #New df with date formated column.
    data1<-reactive({df1<-as.Date(df()$date, format = "%m.%d.%Y") })

 #Output to UI
    output$table <- renderDataTable({data1()})
    output$text1 <-renderDataTable({df()})
    })
```

Shiny is not creating the object `data1` the object `df` works fine.

Comment: try returning the `df()` variable: `data1 <- reactive({df1 <- as.Date(df()$date, format = "%m.%d.%Y");df1})`. Alternatively test for `NULL` and `NA`

Comment: Still does not return it.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
df <- reactive({ df2 <- read.csv(foo(), sep = ";")
          df2$date <- as.Date.character(df2$date,  format = '%d.%m.%Y') 
          df2
      })
```